# Prismatic omen and gruul turf

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have both [Prismatic Omen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPrismatic%20Omen%5d) and [Gruul Turf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGruul%20Turf%5d) on the battlefield, can I tap the Gruul Turf for two of any land type it's become now, or does it still only add one g and r?

Answer (score 7):

Gruul Turf will have 6 separate activated abilities. One of them is to tap for RG, the others each tap for 1 mana, 1 ability for each color. So no, you cannot tap for 2 mana of any color.

Also a note on terminology, tapping a land adds a mana to your pool, it does not add a land or land type.